# How to redirect with form data in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is my situation, may be a little odd though: I login as `admin`, and go to some page with a form, then the authentication fail for some reason (for example, leave too long but not close the page, or disconnect the network and connect later), when i post the form again, it goes to login page. The login page can get `returnUrl` and redirect to the previous page, but **all the form data is lost now**. The final result is a application error page.

The redirect section of login is:

```
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            return this.Redirect(303, returnUrl);
        else
            return this.Redirect(303, FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);
    }
```

So ,how can i redirect with the form data(since many page needs authentication, the form data may vary from action to action)?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot redirect with form data. When you are redirecting you are using a GET request. Form data is only contained in the body of a POST request. You could of course loop through all form data keys and values and append them to the target url as query string parameters but don't forget that there's a limitation to the length of a query string which could vary between the browsers.